# 400 Bad Request with Flask and HTML form

Tags: python, html, forms, post, flask

I'm have a form (that is created in index.html). **When I click submit, however, I get a 400 Bad Request error**. I think it has to do with my app routes in Flask, but I can't figure out a solution...

In Index.html (excerpt):

> ```
> <form class="demographic-form" action="/getsurveyresult" method="post">    
>   Question:    
>   <br>    
>   <input type="checkbox" name="question" value="yes">Check this box!    
>   <br>    
>   <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
> </form>
> ```

In app.py:

```
from flask import *
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.vars = {}

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/getsurveyresults', methods=['POST'])
def processData():
    app.vars['question'] = request.form['question']

    f = open('data.txt' ,'w')
    f.write('question: %s\n' %(app.vars['question']))
    f.close()

    return render_template("getsurveyresults.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have a getsurveyresults.html script in the same folder as index.html. Index.html has no issue rendering.

P.S. I tried replacing action="/getsurveyresult" with action="{{ url_for('getsurveyresult') }}" but I got a werkzeug.routing.BuildError - as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. If the `question` checkbox is not checked then there will be no `question` field in the POST data. Flask raises a subclass of `KeyError` on invalid key lookups on `args` and `form` (just like a normal Python dictionary). This shows up as a 400 error.  If the field is optional use `request.form.get('question')`
2. The argument to `url_for` should be the name of the controller (in this case `processData`), not the URL.

Comment: Yup - I was testing it without checking any of the boxes. This is perfect! I encorporated request.form.get and it no longer throws an error if I don't enter anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo:

```
 @app.route('/getsurveyresults')

 <form class="demographic-form" action="/getsurveyresult"
```

You need to change the @app.route to /getsurveyresult (without the final s), or change the form action to /getsurveyresultS (with the final s). You can also use flask's url_for function:

```
 <form class="demographic-form" action="{{ url_for('processData') }}"
```

Comment: When you use `url_for()` the argument should be the view method name not the URL. See Sean's answer.

Comment: Like IanAuld pointed out, URL_FOR should have pointed to the functions name, I've modified my answer.